# how do i fix pepper's facial recognition after it detects it?

Tags: python, pepper, choregraphe

I'm programming pepper with Choregraphe and I'm trying to define the second interaction after it recognizes the face, but as soon as I start the interaction it gives me this error. Also, if I try to define the global variable it tells me "NameError: global name 'Gender_user' is not defined"

`[ERROR] behavior.box :_safeCallOfUserMethod:125 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11199696904:/second_interaction_20/get_data_7: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/aldebaran/lib/python2.7/site-packages/albehavior.py", line 113, in _safeCallOfUserMethod     func(functionArg)   File "<string>", line 152, in onInput_onStart UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Gender_user' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Please provide your behavior for more explicit help. It looks like you simply coded something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the Python code of your box `get_data`, which references `Gender_user` before it is assigned. Please check your code.